# Converting CALS type rasters for Arcmap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, convert

I have a bunch (think 400+) scanned old portions of maps that are in .cal format, apparently a CALS type raster format. I am able to open them in Autocad Map 3D, but Arcmap does not recognize them. I'd like to (eventually) get them in a GIS, but not sure how to batch convert .cal to something more appropriate to work with in Arcmap.

Answer (score 1):

The [CALS format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CALS_Raster_file_format) is apparently a DoD 1bit raster. I did a quick search and don't see any support for it in ArcGIS, GDAL, or even FME. It seems your best bet would to be locate a specialized converter tool and batch them into PNG, TIF, or something else most GIS can handle. Map3D might have a method of doing so. Below are a few options (random Google results), though I don't know if CALS has georeferencing support or it would survive any translation:

- https://www.reaconverter.com/convert/cal_to_png.html
- http://www.softwarecompanions.com/tiff_viewer.html
- http://command-line-imageconverterplus.com/how-to/folders/cals2tif.htm
- http://www.sfaxtools.com/cals.htm

Full disclaimer on linked apps - as I said they're just Google results and I know nothing about them.